# Da word before reference without comma

Tags: grammar-identification

[In this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72055/using-da-words-before-the-reference-is-stated), it was discussed on using da before the actual fact with a comma. I came across a slight variant of it recently:

> Es gibt auch ~~manche~~ Forschung als beweis dafuer. (me)
>
> Es gibt auch Forschung dazu als Beweis dafuer. (corrected)

I understand why the "manche" is dropped; Forschung is something which is not quantifiable in the linguistic sense. However, why is the "dazu" inserted? Could someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, "dazu" means "on this topic" here (refering to the research). It seems completely optional to me.

I don't think that anyone can explain why this was inserted except for the person who inserted it.

If you'd like to say that the amount of existing research is limited, here are some ways to do that:

> Es gibt auch Forschung (in begrenztem Umfang) als Beweis dafür.
> Es gibt auch (eine begrenzte Anzahl) Forschungsarbeiten ...
> Es gibt auch (ein wenig) Forschung als Beweis dafür.

"Forschung in begrenztem Umfang" and "als Beweis dafür" might be seen as contradictory. You could also say:

> Es gibt auch Forschung (in begrenztem Umfang), die diese These stützt.